# Dataframe search from list and all elemts found in a new column in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df and I need to search if there is any set of elements from the list of keywords or not .. if yes I need to put all these keywords @ separated in a new column called found or not.

My df is like

```
utid | description
123  | my name is harry and I live in newyork
234  | my neighbour is daniel and he plays hockey
```

The list is quite big something like list ={harry,daniel,hockey,newyork}

the output should be like

```
utid | description                                | foundornot
123  | my name is harry and I live in newyork     | harry@newyork
234  | my neighbour is daniel and he plays hockey | daniel@hockey
```

The list is quite big like some 20k keywords  ..also in case not found print NF

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the elements in the `list` if exists each row of `description` column in the `udf` function and make the list of the elements as a string separated by *@* to return it or else *NF* string as

```
val list = List("harry","daniel","hockey","newyork")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def checkUdf = udf((strCol: String) => if (list.exists(strCol.contains)) list.filter(strCol.contains(_)).mkString("@") else "NF")

df.withColumn("foundornot", checkUdf(col("description"))).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+------------------------------------------+-------------+
|utid|description                               |foundornot   |
+----+------------------------------------------+-------------+
|123 |my name is harry and i live in newyork    |harry@newyork|
|234 |my neighbour is daniel and he plays hockey|daniel@hockey|
+----+------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: NF is not getting printed if it is not found

Comment: then you must have missed something . can you recheck again and tally the code with the answer? if not you can update the question and I shall see it